# HTML - How to transform a combobox into a filtered search field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, filter, combobox

Hi I would like to transform a combobox into a filtered search field because the combobox is made up of 60 elements and it is difficult to disfil among these 60 elements to find the element that we search. So I think it's simpler to give the user a chance to grab the item he is looking for and the combobox will give him suggestions automatically according to the list.

We will make an example of a combobox with 5 elements. Here's my code

```
<select name="example">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">A</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

**NOTE:**
I also use bootstrap in case it would be necessary to use it in the code.
Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and here you go

```js
function searchSelect(searchForID, searchInID) {
    var input = document.getElementById(searchForID).value.toLowerCase();
    var output = document.getElementById(searchInID).options;

    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        if (output[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) < 0) {
            output[i].style.display = "none";
            output[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        } else {
            output[i].style.display = "";
            output[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#widthset{
width=500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search:
<input type="text" size="25" ID="searchFor" onkeyup="searchSelect(this.id,'searchIn')">
<br />
<br />
<div class="widthset">
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="searchIn" id="searchIn">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

apply CSS on your own

Answer (score 0):

Give some more details. Is it about fetching the data from database or some other online source. or is it just the script. Give some more details in your question. Edit your question.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. The combobox that I gave as an example, I want to have the possibility of entering to search the element instead of scrolling to search

Comment: Then user can itself type the letters which he/she want to search about.

Comment: exactly ! for example if he/she types B, the list will only show the letters starting with B and it will be enough to select the element that is in the list and which corresponds to the one we are looking for

Comment: do you have an idea ?

Comment: Yeah you can use javascript to do so. Try searching for Populate combobox code. Using javascript would be easy. Ajax and php requires network connectivity and database. I might have helped you but I am superbusy. All the best dude.

Comment: i have no idea ! please help me